# Nav child-menu is not getting minimized at page load

Tags: javascript, css

Nav child-menu is not getting minimized at page load but after clicking on it its working fine. [I also added the image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO1T8.png)

```
        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
          <div class="menu_section">
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> ABCD <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul id="child-menu" class="nav child_menu">
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Filters <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Filter Orders</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /sidebar menu -->
```

This javascript populate the 1st  tag and call to certain function which u may not required.

```
    <!-- for Pupulating the side bar -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var constraintsType = mcosConstraints();
    function functionOne(i) 
    { 
        var ct = constraintsType[i];
    }               
    var output="";
    for(var i=0;i<constraintsType.length;i++)
    {
        output += "<div id=\"ch\" class=\"\" onclick = \"functionOne("+i+")\"><li style=\"line-height: 300%\";><a href=\"\">"+constraintsType[i]+"</a></li></div>";
    }   
    document.getElementById("child-menu").innerHTML=output;
</script>
<!-- for /Pupulating the side bar -->
```

Comment: You didn't show the code you used to minimize the nav-child on page load.

Comment: please add javascript code

Comment: I deleted the code as it was not working and as i closed the file so unable to recover. Can u give me the code for this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ABCD").click(function() {
    $("#child-menu").toggleClass("tmp1 child_menu");
  })
});

var constraintsType = ["Type1", "Type2", "Type3"];

function functionOne(i) {
  var ct = constraintsType[i];
}
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < constraintsType.length; i++) {
  output += '<li id="ch" class="" onclick = "functionOne(' + i + ')><li><a href="">' + constraintsType[i] + '</a></li>';
}
document.getElementById("child-menu").innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.tmp{
  display: block !important;
}
.child_menu {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
  <div class="menu_section">
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
      <li id="ABCD"><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> ABCD <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul id="child-menu" class="nav child_menu">
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Filters <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu">
          <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Filter Orders</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Its not getting minimized on loading the page at the beginning and after words its working fine

Comment: have you write css `.child_menu { display: none;}` ?

Comment: didn't got what you said. I am new to the field so please explain in simple terms

Comment: Its too long and too complicated more than 10 js file and css files are included and couple of graph and plugins are their in the cose so not possible foe me to paste.

Comment: He i edited the post, hope you may be able to identify the problem. The problem is with the javascript file use to populate the <li>. But could'nt able to solve.

Comment: Your comment .child_menu {
  display: none;
} is not working dude.

Comment: Yes, I did that, the child menu should get hidden after adding that, but its not.

Comment: Try this `.child_menu { display: none !important;}`

Comment: But when i hide ch {display:none}; it hides but only the 1st one ie hide Type1 and the rest are visible

Comment: Yes, .child_menu { display: none !important;}  its getting hidden but now js has some issue because its not able to open it

Comment: Still not working, There is some problem in the jquery code $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ABCD").click(function() {
    $("#child-menu").toggle();
  })
});

Comment: i have also changed jQuery code. please read answer properly and then post comment

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ABCD").click(function() {
    $("#child-menu").toggleClass("tmp1 child_menu");
  })
}); your code is still not working even #ABCD click not responding